# Format column as percentage in Openpyxl Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I just want to make certain columns into percentages using Openpyxl for Python. I can't figure out how to change the formatting of the cells to another type?

I've consulted this page:

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/styles.html

But if I try doing:

```
ws['A:A'].style = percent
```

I get ValueError: Style percent exists already. I'm sure I'm making some stupid mistake, but I can't figure out what it is. I've seen other threads about people wanting to change formats to currencies, which uses a different number formatting, but nothing about percentages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only format individual cells not cell ranges or columns or rows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a shame, maybe in an updated version!

Comment: It's now possible, using builtin styles: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html

Comment: @Guts - "maze found | page does not exist"

Comment: here the correct link to styles documentation:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html

Answer (score 1):

@gianluca-tarasconi As per your comment on the styles documentation https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html, it is still applicable to one cell at a time. Is there a way, one can style entire row or column or range of cells. I tried different things only to get `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'style'`

Failed experiments to add percentage to group of cells:

```
In [23]: from openpyxl.styles.numbers import FORMAT_PERCENTAGE

In [27]: from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle

In [31]: highlight = NamedStyle(number_format=FORMAT_PERCENTAGE, name="percent_style")

In [32]: wb.add_named_style(highlight)  # wb is workbook

In [33]: ws1["B"].style = highlight  # ws1 is worksheet
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [33], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 ws1["B"].style = highlight

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'style'


In [34]: ws1["B1:B5"].style = highlight
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [34], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 ws1["B1:B5"].style = highlight

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'style'


In [37]: ws1["B:B"].style = highlight
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [37], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 ws1["B:B"].style = highlight

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'style'
```

Successful experiments are with individual elements:

```
In [35]: for val in ws1["B"]:
    ...:     val.style = highlight # Saved xlsx file contains percent values.


In [43]: for val in ws1["C"]:
    ...:     val.number_format = FORMAT_PERCENTAGE # Saved xlsx file contains percent values here in column C as well.
```

**At present I can only think of an answer by @charlie-clark `You can only format individual cells not cell ranges or columns or rows.` to be true.**

*Wondering if there is any way to format (in this case use percentage) for a column/row/group of cells.*

Comment: thank you. was about to follow your journey