# Append full row to excel with style

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm coding in "python" using "openpyxl" trying to set font 'Arial' to some columns in Excel File but my code write rows good but without font.
Is there a solution to font before writing anything to the file?

Current code when trying to set font the column gets hidden

```
                ## SELECTING THE FILE     
                wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)

                ## CREATTING WORKSHEET IF DOESNT EXIST               
                if bool(x['workbook_name'] in wb.get_sheet_names()) == False:
                    wb.create_sheet(x['workbook_name'])
                    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(x['workbook_name'])

                    sheet['A1'] = 'Tel'
                    sheet['B1'] = 'Fax'
                    sheet['C1'] = 'email'
                    sheet['D1'] = 'address'
                    sheet['E1'] = 'date'

                    sheet.column_dimensions['A'].font = Font(name="Arial")
                    sheet.column_dimensions['B'].font = Font(name="Arial")
                    sheet.column_dimensions['C'].font = Font(name="Arial")
                    sheet.column_dimensions['D'].font = Font(name="Arial")
                    sheet.column_dimensions['E'].font = Font(name="Arial")


                ## DELETE WORKSHEET "SHEET" IF EXISTS
                if bool('Sheet' in wb.get_sheet_names()) == True:
                    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
                    wb.remove_sheet(ws)                        

                ## SELECT SHEET
                sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(x['workbook_name'])

                ## APPEND ROW
                sheet.append([_tel1,_model,_manfc,x['note'],time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")])

                ## SAVE WORKBOOK
                wb.save(filepath)
```

Now i have [this link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#applying-styles) but it doesnt really help , its not clear

Even this simple code gives the same problem, the column gets hidden

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test101.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
sheet['A1'].font = Font(name='Arial')
sheet.append(['hello','world'])
wb.save('test101.xlsx')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format column as percentage in Openpyxl Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849036/format-column-as-percentage-in-openpyxl-python)